# Relationship between optical power and drive current/voltage?

Tags: power-electronics, optics, laser-diode

For a project I'm working on I've got a laser diode whose spec sheet lists the optical power and operating voltage of the module. Unfortunately, the parameter I need most is the drive current. Can the optical power be reasonably approximated as P = VI?

Comment: No. While they get better with every incarnation, they are not able to convert all the electric energy into optical energy. So you are missing a conversion efficiency there. We might help you out more, if it was possible to get the spec sheet for us to see as well.

Comment: Also lasers have a threshold current below which they are non coherent LEDs, the optical power is highly non linear with current.

Comment: Can you give a link to the datasheet for this "module"?

Comment: Far from it. There is a knee current, Ikn or similar where it starts to lase. From there, you have far from 100% efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency of modern laser diodes is very good, somewhere between 50% and 60%, see [RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_diodes.html). Actual drive current should be listed in the datasheet, but for ballpark estimation and budgeting you can use your formula with 50% correction (double the current you got from the power and voltage)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much better to know the biasing voltage and power input to the transceiver's laser diode. Look for the data sheet and find the power out of diode(it would be in dBm at specified operating point). From there you can get some idea but normally in any system you cant get the relationship between input and output power without efficiency.

Answer (score -2):

Lasers must have their own current regulation using optical feedback inside.  You then regulate with PWM.. unless you are talking about low power lasers then you need the CC specs and CC regulator void of overshoot.